# Export to txt what subfolders are empty?

Tags: python

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\shapefiles'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk:
    with open(path1 +'//' + 'exprt' + '//'+'log.txt', 'w') as fw:
        if not os.listdir(root):
            fw.write('%s' % (os.path.join(root,shapefile)) + ' is empty' + '\n')
```

I know about the format solution instead of the %s but I want to do it like this.
Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: What is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. If I print it , it gets printed but it doesn't write to txt anything.

Comment: Does the log file even get created?

Comment: Yes. It's empty.

Comment: If you print to console instead of fw.write, do you see the expected content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's empty because you create new file (overwrite the existing one) for each iteration of your loop. Either change mode to 'a' or open the file and don't close it till the end of the loop (i.e. swap the for loop with with context manager)

EDIT: add code snippets

```
import os
path1 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\shapefiles'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk:
    with open(os.path.join(path1, 'exprt', 'log.txt'), 'a') as fw:
        if not os.listdir(root):
            fw.write('{} is empty\n'.format(os.path.join(root, shapefile)))
```

or

```
import os
path1 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\shapefiles'

with open(os.path.join(path1, 'exprt', 'log.txt'), 'w') as fw:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk:
        if not os.listdir(root):
            fw.write('{} is empty\n'.format(os.path.join(root, shapefile)))
```

of course `shapefile` should be defined in advance (I don't see it in you code)

Comment: cool you saw that. Thanks.Can you write your last approach to code? I simply put it before the for loop and worked though I would like to see what you mean with the other approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Python3.4 and have access to the new stdlib [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib):

```
import pathlib

path1 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\shapefiles'
path1_path = pathlib.Path(path1)

paths = [p for p in path1.rglob("*") if p.is_dir()]
empty_paths = [p for p in paths if not list(p.glob("*"))]

logfile = path1 / "exprt" / "log.txt"
with logfile.open(mode='w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join([f"{p / shapefile} is empty" for p in empty_paths]))
```